# which software to use for following app?

Tags: android, ios

So basically im trying to create an app (for ios/android) that lets you basically put in a few locations and the app basically tells you which route to go so you save the most time to visit all locations.

Also it should be able to tell you which time you would need to leave current location (so gps tracking has to be used) to reach target location in time etc..

I would use xamarin with visual studios, is that good?
also, do i need the google maps api for the gps thing to work?

kind regards for tips!!

Comment: Welcome. Alas, your question is off-topic and likely to be closed. Please read [ask]. Personally, I would code react Native. You do need an API key for Google maps, but it is free (up to a certain usage, which is quite generous) An alternative is Open Street Maps.

Comment: Basically, you should consider using basically less often.  :)

Comment: oh i went to stackoverflow and go to ask question -> ask about software recommendation and it guided me to this site and i thought its ok to ask this here..im sorry if it is wrong post!